# How can I specialize the link element (related-links)

Tags: dita, dita-ot

i'd like to create new elements, based on the [link](http://docs.oasis-open.org/dita/v1.2/os/spec/langref/link.html) element. This would be more comfortable for the author than using the `role` and `otherrole` attributes to specify the link role.

Unfortunately the `DITA-OT 2.2.1` fails with this message:

```
    Required item type of result of template related-links:link. 
    is element(Q{}link); supplied value has item type
    element(Q{}myelement)
```

Is this a valid approach, or should I stick to `otherrole`?

**Update 1:**
The error occurs in the `related-links.xsl`:

```
<!-- Ungrouped links have the default-mode 
     template applied to them. (Can be overridden.) -->
<xsl:template match="*[contains(@class, ' topic/link ')]" 
              mode="related-links:link" 
              name="related-links:link."
              as="element(link)">
  <xsl:sequence select="."/>   <!--- error points to this line -->
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Can you also post the XSLT template + line where the problem occurs? If the issue is consistent maybe you can add a bug on the DITA OT Bugs list.

Comment: This line causes the error [beetle.dita#L23](https://github.com/doctales/org.doctales.terminology/blob/0b7384483956473a7d019091baf7d60f331547ac/samples/beetle.dita#L23).

Comment: Both variants did not work:

- `<!ATTLIST hyponym %global-atts; class CDATA "- topic/link ">`
- `<!ATTLIST hyponym %global-atts; class CDATA "- topic/link termentry/hypernym">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is clearly a bug in the XSLT implementation as you can't use direct tagname checks with any DITA processing because it will fail in the face of specialization as you're seeing.

Side note: assuming your specialization is a domain, the name for the domain should end in "-d" per the DITA naming conventions:

class="- topic/link mylink-d/mylinktype "

This is a convention not a hard requirement but it's useful to be able to look at the @class value and know if an element comes from a domain or a structural specialization.

Comment: It is not a domain specification, but thanks a lot for the reminder. It is a [new topic type for terminology management](https://github.com/doctales/org.doctales.terminology). I filed an issue: [dita-ot#2197](https://github.com/dita-ot/dita-ot/issues/2197)